# vsts release - Azure Container Registry Artifact

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-devops

An application is built and pushed to an Azure Container Registry in one vsts project and is tagged with the application version & build id.

In a separate project I want to do a release whenever a new image is pushed into the repository.
I can use the Azure Container Repository as artifact  but how would I get the correct image tag?

Comment: To answer my own question, you can reference the buildid by using "Release.Artifacts.YourApp.BuildId" this is the imagetag I needed

Answer (score 0):

ACR Provides Webhooks for Push and Delete. Within the Webhook payload, you can find tag information. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-webhook-reference
If you wire up a push webhook to your release definition, just parse out the tag information and you should be good to go. 
Webhook information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-webhook